# Characteristics for 2nd order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

If I have an equation

$p(x)\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + r(x)\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y} + q(x)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=f(x,y,u)$

Where $f$ maybe contains first partial derivatives for $u$.

Can anyone give me a worked example of how to solve this using the method of characteristics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these [lecture notes](http://research.nianet.org/%7Egrossman/lectnotes3_09-ch5.pdf) on the method of characteristics for second-order PDEs, where the method is applied to steady isentropic flow (gasdynamics)

Comment: Just to let you know, the link in this answer can't (/can no longer) be accessed by the general population.